# WSO2 Governance Registry UI customization

Tags: wso2

Folks,
I'd like to have something like the following in our service registry.
I'd like to add a field to the UI that when I click on it in the UI, it does a select from the database and creates a popup with the data returned from that database select.

is this possible?

For instance, I'd like to have a button on the UI page for a service that when clicked, goes to the database and gets all "METHODS" of the service (I would have previously populated customized database fields after analyzing the service definition, and this button would execute a customized select statement to pull the required data out of the db).

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely clear about what your requirements is but i think this might help take look at the doc for RXT[1] and see if you can solve your requirement with that :).

[1] http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=22185121

Thanks, 
Pulasthi